# How to get the object that called the method in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a button that calls a method. I need to access that button inside the method. I don't know how you can access the caller of a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using IBAction for handling button event, the sender passed to you will be your button:

```
- (void) onButtonAction: (id) sender
{
  NSLog(@"sender object description %@", sender);
}
```

Comment: Do you know how I can get the caller of a method in general?

Comment: Mona, I'm not sure this is possible for the general case

Answer (score 5):

```
-(void)myButtonAction: (id)sender
{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass: [UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton* btn = sender;
        // do something! :)
    }
}
```